# Who controls Dangerous Knowledge?

Tags: vernor-vinge, rainbows-end

In Vernor Vinge's *Rainbows End*, Mr. Rabbit takes control of the Greater Scooch-a-mout during the conflict between the Hacek and Scoochi belief circles.

However, it appears that he's evenly matched by the presence of the incarnation of the Hacek circle's Dangerous Knowledge.

Mr. Rabbit later contemplates how wonderful it is that he's met a "new friend", with the implication that this may be someone he considers a relative peer.

Is it ever expanded upon who or what was controlling Dangerous Knowledge?

Answer (score 1):

No.

And the book never explicitly states who/what Mr. Rabbit is either.  Although I thought the book strongly implied Mr. Rabbit was an accidentally created AI - who tried very hard to keep what he was a secret.

I assume therefore that his "new friend" was also an accidentally create AI.

I hope Vernor Vinge decides to write more stories in this Universe.

Comment: I wouldn't go so far as to say that Mr Rabbit is "strongly implied" to be an AI. He's pretty clearly *some* kind of transhuman intelligence, but he could be anything - a collective intelligence, a single person hopped up on nootropics and embedded hardware, a confederation of not-quite sentient AIs... Given the heavy emphasis on cooperation and affiliation in Robert's story in the book, I lean toward the idea that Mr. Rabbit is some kind of collective intelligence. Given all the possible variations, I wouldn't be surprised if the "new friend" is something else, entirely.

Comment: That's actually a good point.  The new friend is different from Mr. Rabbit and that makes him interesting.  This means it is unlikely to be an ordinary human and it is also unlike to be an intelligence like Mr. Rabbit.  So if Mr. Rabbit is a spontaneous AI, the "new friend" could be one of those other alternative.

Comment: Oh, and my reason for stating Mr. Rabbit is "strongly implied to be an AI" is because he seems to have some innate or special knowledge of computers and computer security.  Interestingly, Mr. Rabbit seems to bind himself to a code of conduct even more strictly than the humans of the book - even though he may seem less concerned about human casualties than the humans.

Comment: Also recall that the book's period and setting seem to be events leading up to the singularity.  It's possible he's part of that transition.

Answer (score 1):

Vernor Vinge does not expand upon this, though there are some intriguing possibilities based on the potential identity of Rabbit.  I mentioned in another post the possibility that Rabbit is some kind of ego-level program (like Arne and Sjana in *A Fire Upon the Deep*), and the controller of Dangerous Knowledge may be something/one similar.  This is hinted at in the context of the "new friend" statement, and also earlier when Rabbit notes that one of his adversaries in the fight for control over Zulfikar Sharif's persona is "not entirely incompetent".

If the mind or minds (Rabbit is said by Afred Vaz to controlled by *minds*) on which Dangerous Knowledge is based is an ego-level program, the most likely candidate is Miri, and perhaps the evolving relationship between Robert and his granddaughter is played out in a parallel, virtual manner.  Miri seems to have the respect of Rabbit, though there are others, like Juan Orozco, Xiu Xiang, Lena Gu, or others who may have potential.